# Check if HTML contains anything visible

Tags: c#, html

I want to check in c# if an html document is "visibly empty". Checking InnerHtml is not enough, because the HTML could contain an image or an empty table.

Are there any efficent ways to check a HTML document if there is anything, that translate to something that is not a whitespace?

The complicated way i'm thinking of is removing every html/body/p/br Tag, whitespaces and nbsp items, and checking if anything is left

Comment: what about checking its actual height? :D empty returns 0

Comment: What's with a transparent image or one which size is 0?

Comment: well it depends a bit on the definition of visibly empty :P an empty div with fixed size also will return sth more than 0, not sure if it counts. if so there might be only image processing left :P

Comment: you want to find "visible empty" text in html document?

Comment: To keep it simple, any image counts as content, even empty images.  "Visibly empty" means no text, no images, no tables. When the user sees the page, it should appear as empty.

Its about a text editor framework. When the user leaves the editor "empty", the result should be an empty string instead of a bunch of "useless" html